# Toshiba satellite Keyboard Model P755

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard

I have a Toshiba satellite Laptop p755 model. It was working fine for about a year and half but one day the <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd> (on the number pad), <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd>(left arrow) suddenly stopped working. The other keys are working fine. I did not drop any liquid on it and I did not install any software that can cause the problem.

I tried using on-screen keyboard and it works fine. I borrowed a USB keyboard from a friend and it, again, worked fine. But I want to use my keyboard.

I've tried the following things as a solution, but to no avail.

- I checked for any driver updates related to the keyboard but there were none.
- I turned off the PC, removed the battery and hold the power button for 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

**boot linux live cd and try your keyboard there.**
You can find one for example here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/files/clonezilla_live_alternative/20140915-trusty/clonezilla-live-20140915-trusty-i386.iso/download
burn or write it to usb flash drive and boot from it.
When it boots up press Alt+F2 to enter command prompt and try your keys there...
This is the way how to find out if it is a software or hardware problem.
If the keys are not working, sorry - your keys are dead.. the only option is to have the keyboard replaced. If your laptop is still under warranty, the shop where you bought it should replace the keyboard for free. Otherwise they will propose a price of the new keyboard.
But if the keyboard is working, it is a problem of your windows installation. In that case consider its reinstallation.

Comment: Can you add a part in what to do when the keys indeed turn out to be dead? (like sending the laptop to a shop to get the keyboard replaced, or how to find out what it would cost to do it yourself? With that info, I'd rate this +1

Comment: you are right, I have updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For ghosting purposes keyboards are wired in a way that buttons next to each others aren't wired to consecutive wirings, but rather keys from here and there share a common wire. And it sounds like your keyboard has exactly one of these common wires cut for some reason.

I think your only choice is to get a new one.